# Cannot get children category product in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to get child category products when i click on any link of a parent category, right now my relation is working properly for Single Category,

My table Structure are as follows:

> Product:

[image]

> Category:

[image]

> Product_categories :

[image]

I have created a function for that in controller:

```
 public function show($categorySlug, $subcategorySlug=null)
    {   
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->findBySlug($categorySlug);
        $child_categories=$this->categoryRepository->getChildCategories($category->id);
        if($child_categories->childrenProdut->count()==0)
        {
            $category=$category;
        }
        else{
            $category=$child_categories->childrenProdut;
        }
        return view('site.pages.category', compact('category','child_categories'));
    }
```

> Category Model :

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
public function childrenProdut()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
public function products()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_categories', 'category_id', 'product_id');
}
```

> View :

I',m getting Category and product Data using following statement :

```
 @forelse($category->products as $product)
```

Main Issue :

For single category, I'm getting data i.e. products of that category using the following :

```
public function findBySlug($slug)
{
    return Category::with('products')
        ->where('slug', $slug)
        ->where('menu', 1)
        ->first();
}
```

but i have manipulated the code for the children categories

```
public function getChildCategories($id)
{
    return Category::with('children','products')->find($id); 
}
```

but i'm not getting all child categories but not getting related products. As seen in below images product array is empty, there is some relation issue. Please help to resolve.
[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Are you selecting some specific fields while fetching product information or getting all field values?

Comment: what do you mean *"but i have manipulated the code for the children categories but i'm not getting all child categories but not getting related products"*? Can you elaborate and be specific? What manipulation is done, what result you expect and what you actualy get back?

Comment: sorry, now i have added getChildCategories function in category repository in the question above but here i am not getting products which are under all child categories, i'm getting all the child category as in image but i want the products which are inside that category

Comment: findBySlug is working because this is for single category but there will be case when there will be multiple category and those multiple category must have product associated with each category.

Comment: @sachinkumar: I'm selecting limited fields

Comment: Then sure slug and menu are also include in selecting fields list.

Comment: @sachinkumar: I have two models Category and Product, menu and slug is included in category model and slug of product in slug model, i have issue when multiple children are selected i want the product also with them. findBySlug function relation is working but it is for single category.

Comment: Sometime it become issue when you are not selecting the fields which are using as reference for joining.

Comment: @sachinkumar: $category=$child_categories->childrenProdut; with this relation i'm getting all child categories but only thing i am unable to get is how to create a relation to product so that with each category i also get associated product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, remove childrenProdut() as this function is doing the same as children() function.

**Category Model :**

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_categories', 'category_id', 'product_id');
}
```

Now In case if I want to get all children i.e subcategories and their products then use the following snippets in the controller.

```
Category::with(['children' => function($query){
    //the 'children' relationship should be called within an array
    //this way you could query the relationship as the eloquent model.
    //that way you could call the 'products' relationship inside the Category relationship.
    $query->with('products')
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the above code :  $productsLists = Category::with(['children' => function($query) use ($categorySlug) {
        $query->with('products');
    }])->get(); but it is returning categories but product array within that category is empty, one point more i'm passing here $categorySlug which will fetch only selected categories i.e. it can be multiple child categories.I have updated my table structure and image of what output i'm getting right now.